# Acumatica Select Column Ordering

Tags: acumatica

Is there a way to change the order of the columns in a selector? I added a column to the Shipment Number selector but it always is displayed as the last column. I reordered the columns using PXCustomizeSelectionColumns, but it does not appear to be being used.

```
[PXDBString(15, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
[PXDefault()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = SOShipment.shipmentNbr.DisplayName, Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[AutoNumber(typeof(SOSetup.shipmentNumberingID), typeof(SOShipment.shipDate))]
[PXSelector(typeof(Search2<SOShipment.shipmentNbr,
    InnerJoin<INSite, On<INSite.siteID, Equal<SOShipment.siteID>>, LeftJoinSingleTable<PX.Objects.AR.Customer, On<SOShipment.customerID, Equal<PX.Objects.AR.Customer.bAccountID>>,
    LeftJoinSingleTable<PX.Objects.CR.BAccount, On<PX.Objects.AR.Customer.bAccountID, Equal<PX.Objects.CR.BAccount.bAccountID>>>>>,
    Where2<Match<INSite, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>,
    And<Where<PX.Objects.AR.Customer.bAccountID, IsNull, Or<Match<PX.Objects.AR.Customer, Current<AccessInfo.userName>>>>>>,
    OrderBy<Desc<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>>))]
[PX.Data.EP.PXFieldDescription]

[PXCustomizeSelectorColumns(
    typeof(PX.Objects.SO.SOShipment.shipmentNbr),
    typeof(PX.Objects.SO.SOShipment.shipDate),
    typeof(PX.Objects.CR.BAccount.acctName),
    typeof(PX.Objects.SO.SOShipment.customerID),
    typeof(PX.Objects.SO.SOShipment.customerLocationID),
    typeof(PX.Objects.SO.SOShipment.siteID),
    typeof(PX.Objects.SO.SOShipment.curyID),
    typeof(PX.Objects.SO.SOShipment.status),
    typeof(PX.Objects.SO.SOShipment.shipmentQty),
    typeof(PX.Objects.SO.SOShipment.ownerID))
]
```

New information:
Unfortunately the issue has not been solved. I deleted the comment where I stated that I thought that it was.

So I have done the following:

1. Replaced PX.Objects.CR.BAccount.acctName with PX.Objects.AR.Customer.acctName

   - Result: Proper column order but empty field
2. Did a SQL trace and then ran the resulting query in SSMS

   - Result: The correct data is returned including the account name from BAccount

Comment: Can you post your code? Even if it's not achieving desired results.

Comment: try 'RESET TO DEFAULT' in column configuration

Comment: Where/How do I do that?

Comment: thinkit has something to do with using BAccount vs Customer (as customer inherits BAccount). If you use PX.Objects.AR.Customer.acctName the field shows up but is empty for all records. If you add other fields of SOShipment they show up as expected (correct order) with values. Might not be an issue with the PXCustomizeSelectorColumns as it might be BAccount.acctName having some conflicts

Comment: So you are saying that the selector is causing the issue, correct? If so, how do I get the account name given that Customer.acctName displays an empty field.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Comment: See new information in the OP.

Answer (score 0):

I was developing this on v6.10.1025. It appears that there was a bug in that version that caused this issue. I have upgrade to the latest version, 6.10.1417, and the columns are ordered correctly (I am referencing PX.Objects.CR.BAccount.acctName).

Comment: interesting and thanks for posting. I was using 17.200.0401 so I am guessing I had the same bug when testing your question.

Comment: I am confused by the version that you were using. 17.200.0401?

Comment: 17.2 = 2017R2 and that version is the first release of 2017R2. there has been an update and it might be fixed in that version.